# Is it possible to use output of one oozie action into other without need to save and load from hdfs? Is subworkflow option useful in that?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, oozie, apache-tez

I have to write a oozie workflow which  runs multiple pig actions.These pig actions may be interdependent.I mean output of one pig script will be useful to other. And i want to avoid multiple save and load from hdfs. How can this be achieved?Can I use TEZ DAG to combine all pig scripts in DAG structure and run one Java action from Oozie?

Answer (score 1):

In oozie you cannot pass output of one node to other node (without storing in HDFS). You can implement PigServer (pig java API) to execute multiple pig scripts. In one java programs using pigserver  its always easy to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you consider writing intermediate results to HDFS as not desired? You can tune HDFS replication factor as you wish, and even set it to 1, which is equivalent to writing to a local filesystem.